# Inserting data two times in foreach loop with multiple arrays

Tags: php

I have a working code

```
<?php

$con    =   mysql_connect('localhost','test','test');
mysql_select_db('test',$con);


require_once("xml2json.php");

$testXmlFile = 'myxml.xml';

$xmlStringContents = file_get_contents($testXmlFile); 
$jsonContents = "";
$jsonContents = xml2json::transformXmlStringToJson($xmlStringContents);
$obj =json_decode($jsonContents);
$rows = array();
foreach($obj->rss->channel->item as $item) {

 $rows[] = "('".mysql_real_escape_string($item->title)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($item->description)."')";

 } 
        $del_horoscope = "delete from jos_horoscope";
        mysql_query($del_horoscope);

        $query = "INSERT INTO `jos_horoscope` (`title`,`description`) VALUES ".implode(', ',$rows);
        print_r ($query);
        mysql_query($query);
  // Do the query - do NOT show the output of mysql_error() in a production environment!
  if (!mysql_query($query)) echo 'Oh no! Something went wrong with the query: '.mysql_error();

?>
```

But data is inserting twice with every run of this script. I am using delete statement to delete the data first before inserting new one.Can anyone please help me solve this twice problem. Here is teh screenshot of twice Data filled .https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoRDQ.png

NEW EDIT

Here is the INSERT QUERY echo http://pastebin.com/btZ7f85a
The data is not duplicate.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't have working code by the looks of this example, you forgot to close off the password string in your `mysql_connect()` ;)

Comment: Is the data duplicated 1) in the xml? 2) in the json? 3) in the foreach loop?

Comment: @DarylGill actually that a typo mistake before posting here . Thanks I have edit it now . :)

Comment: @Patashu nope I echo the data and is not duplicate. Its one in the array. Please see here the echo Data Insert query http://pastebin.com/btZ7f85a

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO it's deprecated as of 5.5 but it still works just fine.  It's just a soft deprecation.  His code is too simple to get into complicated PDO functions.  Mysqli would work but he has to ensure his host has the mysqli library installed.

Comment: inserting twice mean 1: $rows[] is duplicate 2: this php run mysql_query($query) twice  3.this php run twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested, but try something like this.  I changed the delete to TRUNCATE which will drop all data in the table.  I also changed the way the INSERTs work rather than 1 long ass insert I changed it to multiple inserts.  There shouldn't be a huge performance hit.  Give it a try, let me know.

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect('localhost','test','test');
mysql_select_db('test',$con);

require_once("xml2json.php");

$testXmlFile = 'myxml.xml';

$xmlStringContents = file_get_contents($testXmlFile); 
$jsonContents = xml2json::transformXmlStringToJson($xmlStringContents);
$obj =json_decode($jsonContents);
$rows = array();

foreach($obj->rss->channel->item as $item) 
{
    $rows[] = "('".mysql_real_escape_string($item->title)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($item->description)."')";
} 

// Remove Data in Table.
$truncate = mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE jos_horoscope");

foreach($rows as $row)
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO `jos_horoscope` (`title`,`description`) VALUES $row";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG  But now the error is 


You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''What\'s special today for you','Your birth on the 25th day of the month (7 ener' at line 1

Its due to special character .:(

Comment: Updated, sorry, forgot to add VALUES before $row.  Try again!

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG It worked :D:D :D Thanks alot ..I learned new things from you .. Thank you

Comment: No problem, hope this helped. On a side note, make your spaces cleaner ;).  I'm really picky about how my code looks hehe..